# Replacing PowerShell Liternal Action/CallBack Function Reference With String Variable?

Tags: powershell

If I have a powershell command...

```
$theEvent=Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $theWatcher -EventName EventRecordWritten -SourceIdentifier $theId -Action { OnEvent $($args[$ONE]) }
```

Where 'OnEvent' is defined function, the above works, when the event fires the action setting invokes the call back passing one parameter.

However, I need to pass in a string variable with the name of the defined function, do something like...

```
$theAction="OnEvent"    
$theEvent=Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $theWatcher -EventName EventRecordWritten -SourceIdentifier $theId -Action { $theAction $($args[$ONE]) }
```

How does one do such?  Clearly the '{' and '}' are creating a code script block, but not sure how to get such to evaluate the '$theAction' string and replace said variable with a function pointer?  Pointing the OnEvent function?

Comment: I think you need to look at [`Invoke-Expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2). Build your command as you would any string with literal and variable portions. There are all sorts of options for string manipulation in **PowerShell** -- I tend to favor the [-f (Format operator)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f).